# Display an article's Access Level on the article's page

Tags: articles, acl

For a website of an educational institute I would like to show registered users what the article's access levels are. In this case the access levels for articles can be "Students", "Teachers" or "Students and Teachers".

How can I display an article's Access Level on the article's page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but the best possible way I can think of is developing a small content plugin.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_content_plugin

You may want to implement onContentAfterTitle event to display your custom content below the article title.